# how to access only whitelisted site

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

How to make browsers access only white listed sites?
Is there any addon in which if If add "google.com", I shall be able to open only google.com (not even mail.google.com or www.google.com)

Even if there are some requests in background from other domains (amazon, akamai etc), those shall be blacked too..

Is it possible?
I can see all the request in firebug, but can't block them.

Why I want to do it?
I need to check the behaviour of a particular site when some all or the resources(css, js) failed to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, I would check out [Whitelist for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whitelist-for-chrome/pocjkchlmhkjafdpmkklknmjhokobgmh?hl=en). It is easy enough to install and create rules on. I can whitelist only main domains too. By adding the `WWW` in front of a site, it will allow only the `WWW` subdomain to be displayed (`www.google.com` allowed but not `mail.google.com`).

If you are using IE, it is not as simple. I would take a look at this article on [Whitelisting Internet Explorer sites](https://security.berkeley.edu/content/how-do-i-enable-web-site-whitelisting-microsoft-internet-explorer?destination=node/453). It guides you through making a "fake" proxy server so only certain sites will be displayed.

If you are using Firefox, there are a lot of add-ons that can whitelist sites, but none of them really stand out as being really great. You will have to [look through the list](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=whitelist&appver=&platform=) to see if any of them fit what you need.

One other note, if you whitelist a site, then all the scripts on that site will be able to run to. Most sites have about 10-50 scripts run when the page loads to either: pull content data, send tracking info back to metric websites (such as Google Analytics), load ads, and load user interface JavaScript. You might want to look into getting a script blocker too if you don't want sites making all of those background requests.